# Trouble creating new directory and adding assets into that directory Android

Tags: android, directory, storage, assets, mkdir

ok so in my app i am adding image icons to the users sd card so they can change out whichever ones they want. im trying to add a folder to their external storage that the images from my assets folder will copy into. no matter what i try either nothing copies or the images copy directly to the sdcard without creating the folder.

heres what i got:

// Buffer size used.
    private final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        AssetManager assetFiles = getAssets();

        // MyHtmlFiles is the name of folder from inside our assets folder
        String[] files = assetFiles.list("Depth Slick Icons");

        // Initialize streams
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            if (files[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Depth Slick Icons")
                    || files[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("js")) {

                /*
                 * @Do nothing. images and js are folders but they will be
                 * interpreted as files.
                 * 
                 * @This is to prevent the app from throwing file not found
                 * exception.
                 */

            } else {

                /*
                 * @Folder name is also case sensitive
                 * 
                 * @MyHtmlFiles is the folder from our assets
                 */
                in = assetFiles.open("Depth Slick Icons/" + files[i]);

                /*
                 * Currently we will copy the files to the root directory
                 * but you should create specific directory for your app
                 */
                out = new FileOutputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Depth Icons/" + files[i]);
                copyAssetFiles(in, out);

            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static void copyAssetFiles(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    try {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read;

        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and yes permissions are set in manifest.

"Depth Slick Icons" is the folder in assets and "Depth Icons" is the folder im trying to create to put the images into.

Comment: ok after posting this on g+ i found the solution:

File outDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Depth Icons");
outDir.mkdirs();
out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outDir, files[i]));

now one final question... if i have a second folder that i wanted to do the same thing to how would i add that second folder going to a second destination?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create the directory first inside Depth Slick Icons using mkdir() function.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29